# Can we set an exception to a wild card redirect using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have set a wildcard redirect in one of my old sites' `.htaccess` which redirects all the requests to same page on the new domain:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd like the homepage of the old domain, to redirect to a specific page on new domain. So I added this line on top of the wildcard redirect rule

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/specific-page/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't work though. Could you please explain where I went wrong?

I tested it through this tool https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it shows that there are no issues with my rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) belong to different Apache modules and consequently run independently and at different times during the request. On Apache, `Redirect` actually runs *after* `RewriteRule`, despite the apparent order in the config file.

So, in the directives you posted, the `RewriteRule` redirect is actually "winning" and redirecting the request since it is being processed first.

> ```
> Redirect 301 / https://example.com/specific-page/
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is also prefix-matching, so a source URL such as `/` (a single slash) will actually match *everything*, not just requests for the document root (homepage). And everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So the above directive would redirect `/<something>` to `https://example.com/specific-page/<something>`.

To redirect a *specific* URL to a different location, you need to add an entirely separate rule before the more general redirect.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect the document root (homepage) only
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/specific-page/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** Note that `^$` (an empty string) matches the requested URL-path `/` (a single slash) only. In per-directory config (ie. `.htaccess`), `RewriteRule` matches the URL-path less the slash prefix. (Strictly speaking it matches the URL-path less the directory-prefix, which is the location of the `.htaccess` file itself and always ends with a slash.)

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. It is advisable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

> ```
> #Options +FollowSymLinks
> ```

`FollowSymLinks` is required for mod_rewrite to function, but this is probably already enabled in your server config.

> I tested it through this tool https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it shows that there are no issues with my rules.

That tool is primarily used for testing mod_rewrite. And in this instance has got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the lucid explanation, @MrWhite. It works like a charm. Speaking of `Redirect` (mod_alias), how would I write the rule to **only redirect the homepage** to a specific page (as the forward slash is matching everything like you said)?

Comment: You can't do that with the `Redirect` directive - it always uses "simple" prefix-matching. You would need to use the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead, which uses regex-matching. eg. `RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://example.com/specific-page/`. Note that in `.htaccess`, mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` matches the URL-path _less the slash prefix_. So, whilst `RedirectMatch` uses `^/$`, `RewriteRule` uses `^$` (as shown in my answer).

Comment: But note the potential conflict with mod_alias and mod_rewrite as mentioned in my answer. Generally, if you are already using mod_rewrite for rewrites/redirects then you should use mod_rewrite throughout.